# Javascript Prompt Cancelled Not Behaving in While Loop

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have a prompt that basically is a required field and cannot contain a decimal.  I have a while loop that should continue to prompt the user for information until a number is indicated regardless of whether OK or Cancel are clicked.  Everything works fine as long as the OK button is clicked.  It continues to prompt if left blank and OK is clicked or if a number with a decimal is provided and OK is clicked.  But if cancel is clicked, it doesn't continue to prompt.

```
var rmiles = prompt("Please indicate actual miles driven for payroll");
    while (rmiles == null | rmiles == "null" | rmiles == " " | rmiles.indexOf(".") != -1) {
        alert("Mileage is required when arriving on site and can only be whole numbers.  No Decimals.  Please enter 0 if you did not intend to arrive on site.");
        rmiles = prompt("Please indicate actual miles driven for payroll");
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like the anti-christ of user experience. Is there a reason you're using prompts and alerts instead of a required field in a lightbox or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your `while` condition - you are doing [bitwise OR `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) on all the conditions. This means that `rmiles.indexOf(".")` is always called, even when `rmiles` is set to `null` by `prompt` when Cancel is clicked. This is because bitwise OR will not short-circuit.

Try the [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) which does short-circuit and thus avoids the null reference error:

```
while (rmiles == null || /*...*/
```

Comment: That totally worked.  I'll accept your answer in a few minutes as soon as this thing lets me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because `rmiles` is null when the user clicks 'cancel'... so `rmiles.indexOf` produces an error/exception and kills the loop.